# div not taking full width of screen on mobile, when there's a wide table underneath

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Having read a lot of other posts for 'div not taking full width', I still can't find an answer as to why the following happens with my website:

I have a responsive topnav navigation bar that works perfectly in Chrome on a Win11 machine. On an Android mobile however, the topnav only takes the full width of the browser when the table is less 'narrow'. It seems that when the table becomes wider, the topnav doesn't follow suit.

HTML + PHP:

```
<?php
// Include the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

$usr = $_GET['usr'];

// Fetch measurements (in descending order)
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM ".$usr." ORDER BY ts DESC");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <title>MariaDB Bloeddruk</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopNav">
    <?php include("../header.php") ?>
</div>

<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>Tijd</th>
                <th>Bovendruk</th>
                <th>Onderdruk</th>
                <th>Hoge Bloeddruk</th>
                <th>Hartslag</th>
                <th>Onregelmatige Hartslag</th>
                <th>AF Modus</th>
                <th>AF gedetecteerd</th>
                <th>Manchet OK</th>
                <th><a class="button" href="add.php?usr=<?php echo $usr ?>">Nieuwe meting</a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            // Print measurements
            while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                $dt = substr($res['ts'],0,10);
                $tm = substr($res['ts'],-8,8);
                echo "<td>".$dt."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$tm."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$res['sys_bp']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$res['dia_bp']."</td>";
                echo "<td><input ".($res['high_bp'] == 1 ? "checked" : "")." type='checkbox' onclick='return false;'</td>";
                echo "<td>".$res['hr']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".($res['irregular_rythm'] == '' ? "</td>" : "<input ".($res['irregular_rythm'] == 1 ? "checked" : "")." type='checkbox' onclick='return false;'</td>");
                echo "<td><input ".($res['af_mode'] == 1 ? "checked" : "")." type='checkbox' onclick='return false;'</td>";
                echo "<td>".($res['af_detected'] == '' ? "</td>" : "<input ".($res['af_detected'] == 1 ? "checked" : "")." type='checkbox' onclick='return false;'</td>");
                echo "<td><input ".($res['cuff_ok'] == 1 ? "checked" : "")." type='checkbox' onclick='return false;'</td>";
                echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?usr=".$usr."&ts=$res[ts]\">Bewerken</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?usr=".$usr."&ts=$res[ts]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Weet u zeker dat u deze meting wilt verwijderen?')\">Verwijderen</a></td>";
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

rendered HTML/code snippet:

```css
body {
        font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: calc(16px + 0.25vw);
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #a6e1fa;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #001c55;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

a {
    color: #0a2472;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #0e6ba8;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

table th {
    background-color: #0e6ba8;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
        padding: 18px 12px;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #caf0f8;
}

table tr {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #0e6ba8;
}

table td {
    padding: 12px;
        text-align: center;
}

table td:first-child {
        white-space: nowrap;
}

form table {
    width: 33%;
}

form table tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #fff;
}

form table tfoot {
    background-color: #0e6ba8;
}

form table td:first-child {
        white-space: normal;
}

.button {
    border: 1px solid #001c55;
        border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #001c55;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px;
    min-width: 100px;
        white-space: nowrap;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #001c55;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input {
        font-size: inherit;
}

input[type=number] {
        width: calc(4 * (16px + 0.25vw));
        text-align: center;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
        width: calc(16px + 0.25vw);
        height: calc(16px + 0.25vw);
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
        accent-color: #0a2472;
        background-color: #000;
}

input[type=submit] {
    border: 1px solid #001c55;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #001c55;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 100px;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #001c55;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit].cancel {
    background-color: #bbb;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
}

input[type=submit].cancel:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #bbb;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.error { 
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="nl"><head>
    <title>MariaDB Bloeddruk</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopNav">
    <a href="../">Home</a><a href="/bloeddruk/index.php?usr=joost" class="active">Bloeddruk - Joost</a><a href="/vijver/">Vijverwater</a><a href="/water/">Watermeter</a><a href="/lekkage/">Waterlekkage</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon" onclick="topNavStyle()"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></div>

<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Datum</th>
                <th>Tijd</th>
                <th>Bovendruk</th>
                <th>Onderdruk</th>
                <th>Hoge Bloeddruk</th>
                <th>Hartslag</th>
                <th>Onregelmatige Hartslag</th>
                <th>AF Modus</th>
                <th>AF gedetecteerd</th>
                <th>Manchet OK</th>
                <th><a class="button" href="add.php?usr=joost">Nieuwe meting</a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>2022-10-29</td><td>09:23:00</td><td>140</td><td>80</td><td><input checked="" type="checkbox" onclick="return false;" <="" td=""></td><td>50</td><td></td><td><input type="checkbox" onclick="return false;" <="" td=""></td><td></td><td><input type="checkbox" onclick="return false;" <="" td=""></td><td><a href="edit.php?usr=joost&amp;ts=2022-10-29 09:23:00">Bewerken</a> | <a href="delete.php?usr=joost&amp;ts=2022-10-29 09:23:00" onclick="return confirm('Weet u zeker dat u deze meting wilt verwijderen?')">Verwijderen</a></td></tr></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML and not the PHP code. The browser doesn't care about PHP. Only include the minimum amount of HTML so we can reproduce your problem. (One row of your table might be enough)

Comment: @cloned, , like so? I've added it as a code snippet.

Comment: It happens because body takes the viewport width. Your table _overflows_ the width of the body, but does not increase it.

Comment: Thx @CBroe, that was sufficient for me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it solved by adding max height/width and auto overflow to the `div` containing the table:

CSS added:

```
.tableContainer {
        max-width: 100vw;
        max-height: 100vh;
        overflow:auto;
}
```

And of course classified the div that wraps the table as "tableContainer":

```
<div class="tableContainer">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Datum</th>
...
```